# Chef 10: How to use remote_file or similar to get a file from a Windows share?

Tags: ruby, windows, chef-infra

I'm trying to use `remote_file` to cache a local copy of a large package on a Windows share. How is this done?

I can't get it to work with a drive-letter-based path, a UNC-based path, or a `file:` URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a trick that I think is pretty neat.  I created the following definition (and put it in `definitions/default.rb`):

```
define :file_from_network, :action => :create do
   myPath = (params[:path] || params[:name])
   mySource = params[:source]

   if File.exist?(mySource)
      file myPath do
         action params[:action]
         content File.open(mySource) {|io| io.read}
      end
   else
      Chef::Log.error("File #{mySource} not found!")
   end
end
```

Definitions do not work quite the same way resources do, but this was easy to implement and does what I need it to do. The in-memory read makes it impractical for huge files, of course, but it allows Chef to check that the content is different before triggering an action on the file resource.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have windows to test, but something like this should work:

```
require 'fileutils'
remote_path = '...'
local_path = '...'

ruby "cache-#{remote_path}" do
    block  { FileUtils.copy_file(remote_path, local_path) }       
    not_if { File.exists?(local_path) }
end
```