# Chef copy file (via remote_file?) from a windows share

Tags: chef-infra

I had to copy some files to a windows host off of a windows share the other day. To my horror I realized there's no built in option for that:

- remote_file doesn't accept a windows network share as a source
- windows_package (from the windows cookbook) is only for running installers (.msi / .exe etc)
  ... ?

Is the only solution to this writing a custom helper library that does the file copy? This sounds like core functionality that should exist within remote_file. Am I missing something here or does Chef indeed have no built-in option for a simple file copy off of windows shares?

Comment: There are like 5 questions in your question.

Comment: There's only one I could find (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409881/chef-10-how-to-use-remote-file-or-similar-to-get-a-file-from-a-windows-share?rq=1). And the solution is a helper file. Feel free to post the url of one decent answer.

Comment: I meant - you asked 5 different questions in **this** post. What is your actual question? It sounds like you are just asking rhetorical questions...

Comment: What is the suggested method of copying files located on a windows share (e.g \\theshare.domain\file) to a windows chef node?

Answer (score 7):

To get a file from a windows network share using `remote_file`, you just have to use the correct URL syntax (which is indeed a bit non-obvious):

```
remote_file "foo" do
  source "file:////server/path/to/file"
  path "/path/to/local/file"
end
```

That way, it works even when when copying stuff from CIFS shares.

Comment: Argh... Thank you. I couldn't find this in the documentation. I'm on the way to work so I'll try it in a bit...

Comment: This actually didn't work. The syntax should be remote_file "path to put it on the node". It would work for a local file but from a windows share it isn't.

Comment: The behavior here was [changed recently](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4472) (and might not be released yet). Could you try it with 3 slashes instead of four?

Comment: Actually with two slashes you're creating a local file. Three slashes throw the following error:
FATAL: NoMethodError: remote_file[test_copy] (production_
test::web_server line 25) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined me
thod `+' for nil:NilClass

(line 25 is my remote_file block)

Comment: I've opened a feature request in case this is simply not supported right now: https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-5350

Answer (score 0):

3 years later, I still can't copy a file from a share. But I found a workaround with mounting:

```
directory 'c:/mydirectory' do
  recursive true
end

mount "P:" do
  device '\\\\myserver\\myshare'
  username "myusername"
  password "mypassword"
end

remote_file "c:/mydirectory/myfile.txt" do
  source 'file:///P:/path_behind_myshare/myfile.txt'
end

mount "P:" do
  device '\\\\myserver\\myshare'
  action :umount
end
```